# How to remove a class on second click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically what I want to do is adding the `.ani` class to the clicked element and removing the `.ani` from all, **but** I also need to remove the `.ani` from the element which already have it on second click.

As you can see the regular add and removing is working fine but I can not remove the `.ani` on existing element. How can I fix this?

```js
$(".list").on('click', function() {
  $('.list').removeClass("ani");
  if ($(this).hasClass('ani')) {
    $(this).toggleClass("ani");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("ani");
  }
});
```

```css
.list {
  height: 60px;
  width: 160px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ani {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are over complicating this task. Take a look at the code below (posting only the JS as HTML and CSS are the same):

```
$(".list").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("ani").siblings().removeClass("ani");
});
```

**A breakdown of what this does:**

1. use `toggleClass` on the item clicked to add remove the class on the
   item
2. get all siblings of the clicked item and remove the class from them

**How this works:**

The bit of code in the example above uses something called method chaining where you execute multiple methods on the same jQuery Object. This is possible because most jQuery methods return a jQuery Object, post-execution. This makes it easier and faster to run a bunch of operations on the same set of elements. One thing that you need to be mindful about when chaining is the sequence of method calls - changing the order of methods that you use may result in adverse effects (i.e: most traversal methods in jQuery returns a different set of elements).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/darshanags/kz2wdo09/

Answer (score 2):

Check this one. Just update `onclick` method. All other code is the same. I posted one is single line code and one if-else code which is commented. You can use which one is more comfortable for you. You are first removing ani class that was a bug in your code.

```js
$(".list").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("ani").siblings().removeClass("ani");
  /*if($(this).hasClass("ani")){
    $(".list").removeClass("ani");
  } else {
    $(".list").removeClass("ani");
    $(this).addClass("ani");
  }*/
});
```

```css
.list {
  height: 60px;
  width: 160px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ani {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
```

Comment: You beat me by a couple minutes, I swear I didn't copy your code!

Comment: @JoséA.Zapata No Problem I have 2 answers first I pasted this one and second I just updated. SO posted both answers here.

Comment: Thanks, the second one is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
$(".list").on('click', function() {
  $('.list').removeClass("ani");
  if ($(this).hasClass('ani')) {
    $(this).toggleClass("ani");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("ani");
  }
});
```

You're removing the class of every `.list` element, therefore the `$(this).hasClass('ani')` will always be false (you just removed the `ani` class of every single `.list` element, including the clicked one), so the line `$(this).addClass("ani")` will always be executed.

The solution is simple. Check if the clicked element has the `ani` class and if so, remove it, otherwise add it:

```
$(".list").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('ani')) {
        $(this).removeClass("ani");
    }
    else {
        $('.list').removeClass("ani");
        $(this).addClass("ani");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to remove class `ani` on all the elements except the clicked one. You can use `not()`

```js
$(".list").on('click', function(evt) {
    $(".list").not($(evt.currentTarget)).removeClass("ani");
    $(evt.currentTarget).toggleClass("ani");
 
});
```

```css
.list {
  height: 60px;
  width: 160px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ani {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
<div class="list"></div>
```